# Проблема с UI Сanvas в мобильной игре

Tags: unity3d, ui, unity3d-android

Существует много видов экранов с разным разрешением, игра уже почти была закончена и я перешел к тестированию на втором мобильном устройстве. Базовое имеет разрешение 2340*1080 (20/9), а ошибка всплыла на FHD( 1920*1080 ) Ui Оказался полностью сжатым. При этом в самом редакторе при проверки на разных разрешениях везде хорошо всё выглядит. Какими настройками это решается? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "сжатым"? Показали бы скриншот где всё хорошо для сравнения. Я не понимаю на что указывают красные пометки.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, то, что текстуры размыты, то это настраивается в самой текстуре `Resize Algorithm:Bilinear`,  `Format:RGBA`, `Compression:на выбор`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Canvas-е есть компонент `Canvas Scaler`. У него параметр `UI Scale Mode` по умолчанию стоит `Constant Pixel Size`. Вам надо будет изменить его на `Scale With Screen Size` который подгоняет игру по масштабам экрана. Если у вас игра создана на масштаб 20/9 то например на 16/9 будет немного сжатым, но это практически будет незаметно. К тому же вы можете это исправить, если задать конкретный размер объектам а не по процентам экрана.

Comment: Этот режим у меня и стоит, но при этом работает некорректно

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев тогда проверьте параметр `Match Width or Height`. Он должен быть `Expand`. А параметр `Reference Resolution` должен совпадать с разрешением экрана на котором вы создали. У вас по идеи должен быть `x:`2340, `y:`1080